# Dynamically injecting a stylesheet that has @font-face causes flash of invisible text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-face

I dynamically inject a stylesheet which I obtain from an external source into my page. This stylesheet contains @font-face rules which causes my text to flash invisible for a second.

I tried resolving it by using `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` however the stylesheet does not appear in the list of document stylesheets (I assume because its an external source?)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/ or https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-font-display/

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm unable to edit the external CSS file, if I could I would just delete the font-face declarations

Answer (score 0):

Update: To avoid the flash of invisible text add `&display=swap` to the end of the Google Font URL.